# Puzzle with a wrong solution

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]
I finished this word puzzle, but I don't think I solved it correctly. Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Ah, I see what you've done here - let me help you correct it ;-)*

As you suspect, your answers (reading across the rows) are all incorrect. How can we tell this? Because...

> ...there is a way to choose a **synonym** of each of your answers so that the word spelled out in a row *uses some arrangement of all the letters of the row above plus one additional letter* - which would surely be the intended puzzle mechanism!
>
>  Without knowing the original clues you had to work with, we can still solve this by looking for appropriate synonyms of the words you have inputted.

If you do this correctly you should get the following output, which satisfies the puzzle's in-built mechanism:

> [image: Solved puzzle]
>
>  (Here, 'I' is the Roman numeral for the number 'one', an equivalent of 'a'...)

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: @justhalf The pyramid appearance of the puzzle invoked the idea of rot13(jbeqf gung tebj ol bar yrggre ng n gvzr. V gura ernfbarq gung gur 'vapbeerpg jbeqf' zhfg unir orra ragrerq orpnhfr gurl fngvfsvrq n cnegvphyne pebffjbeq-glcr pyhr, naq gung gur pbeerpg nafjref zhfg gurersber or flabalzf bs gurfr nafjref. V fcbggrq GUVA naq XVGPURAF svefg, gura jvgu guvf gurbel shyyl sbezrq naq nccrnevat gb or onpxrq hc, jbexrq onpxjneqf guebhtu UVG, UV naq V, abgvprq RGUAVP, naq gura svyyrq va gur erznvavat tncf jvgu GUVAR naq GUVPXRA.)

Comment: The first word of the puzzle and the first word of the correct solution are not rot13(flabalzf). Are they ?

Comment: @Jeffrey See the last line of my answer for an explanation about that one :)